# Very basic rewrite-rule question

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/index.html
```

And want a rule to rewrite the above into this:

```
 http://www.mydomain.com
```

In other words, remove the index.html part of the code...

Something like this maybe:

```
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [NC]
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

When you type www.domain.com into the browser, offcourse index.html is opened.
But when you click on "home" on the menu on my website, the entire full url is displayed, which I want to avoid. So when hitting "home" www.domain.com/index.html is shown... But not when entering www.domain.com in the adress bar, then only that will show, but index.html comes up anyways.

So yes, I need this:

```
www.domain.com/
```

Not this:

```
www.domain.com/index.html
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that? www.mydomain.com should refer to the index.html...

Comment: Do you want to redirect a request for /index.html to /, so that the index.html part does not appear in the browser, or rewrite the index.html part to the page that shows up by default when calling /?

Comment: i think http://www.mydomain.com will open the index.html anyways.

Comment: Check my update all. I just need a rewrite, not a change of path

Comment: @Hippo, @aadravid: No, if exists / might as well refer to index.php... Maybe Camran wants to redirect "index.html" to "index.php"...

Comment: **From the FAQ:** When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Comment: Why not change the link on the home button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect requests for /index.html to /

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [NC]
```

Replace "index.html" with "/", not "" with "index.html"