# RewriteRule for character after slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to apply RewriteRule for specific pages in my website.

Original link :

```
 www.abc.com/category/foo.html
```

How will I apply RewriteRule to redirect to homepage (www.abc.com) if any link contains any character (not number) after the slash (category/_123etcetc) "www.abc.com/category/" ?

For example;

i want to redirect www.abc.com/category/apple.html or www.abc.com/category/key.html to homepage but i don't want to redirect www.abc.com/category/1-apple.html or www.abc.com/category/123-key.html

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: It's not clear to me which urls you want to redirect, and which urls you want to leave alone. Regardless, this seems to be a very basic rewrite to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Very basic rewrite-rule question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590978/very-basic-rewrite-rule-question)